# What is the international charcode value of this string?

Tags: character-encoding, dart, dart-html

I have a string `<...>` (less-than;3x full-stop;greater-than), which I need to convert into its charcode value in order to check if the user pressed these three keys in the specified order (look at the string) on his keyboard (imagine something like konami-code). How to get the charcode value of this string?

I tried some combinations, but it worked just with the english keyboard layout. It hadn't worked with another keyboard layouts (like czech, italian, german). Is there any good solution which doesn't depend on the keyboard layout and keyboard shortcuts, but depends just on the letters typed?

Comment: Where do you get the input from (HTML input field, console, ...)? Why do you need the charcode to compare and not just compare the chars? What you want is possible but a bit more context would it make easier to answer your question.

Comment: Do you know konami code? So this letter sequence is something like konami. User presses on his keyboard that string and the app makes hidden action. And I want to code it. I want to use the konami_code pub package and my goal is to get keyboard-layout-independent combination of charcodes for that purpose.

Comment: And it doesn't matter where in my app the user presses this combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like

```dart
void main() {
  '<...>'.codeUnits.forEach(print);
}
```

> 60
>   46
>   46
>   46
>   62

or

```dart
void main() {
  String s = '<...>';
  print(s.codeUnitAt(0));
  print(s.codeUnitAt(1));
  ...
}
```

which produces the same output.

If this is not what you are looking for, improving your question might help.

Answer (score 1):

The character codes of the five characters is easy to get: `"<...>".codeUnits.toList()`.
It's [60, 46, 46, 46, 62] if you want it literally.

It seems your problem is that you want to detect the *keyboard codes* corresponding to pressing these *keys* on a keyboard.

I'll assume we are in a browser setting. In that case, the keyboard events will contain a `charCode` which should be what you need. Even on foreign (from wherever you are) keyboards, the charCode should be correct - unless the browser misunderstands the keyboard completely, and then the user will have bigger issues.

https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.KeyboardEvent#id_charCode